# How to merge many VRT file into one

Tags: gdal, maptiler

I have many VRT files generated using **gdal_translate** originally for adjacent images.

Is there away to merge all those VRT file into one VRT file so that when I run **gdal2tiles.py** I only need to give it this one composite VRT file?

I thought first gdal_wrap will do the trick, but it turn out that gdal_wrap images into one single image.. However, I dont want to merge images, I would like to merge VRT file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `gdalbuildvrt` utility in GDAL since 1.6.1 - which merges multiple input files into one VRT mosaic file. See this official documentation for usage details:

http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html

You just need to list all the individual files and the output filename very probably.

You have tagged your questions with "maptiler" label, which refers to http://www.maptiler.com/ product. MapTiler is able to render multiple files out of the box and is not using VRT at all internally. It is more efficient to supply the individual input files to maptiler directly, then to create a VRT and pass it to the software. VRT introduces artificial internal block size for reading the data - which slows down the tile rendering process, in some cases significantly.
Feel free to request a demo of MapTiler Pro and compare the speed, size and quality of the map tiles you receive - and post the results here.

Comment: I tried "gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list file_list.txt output.vrt"  but I got "Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support ungeoreferenc
ed image. Skipping input1.vrt" .... and output "output.vrt" file is not generated. But my input1.vrt is generated using "gdal_translate" so it have georeferenc.
e